# Change Query Text in Birt RPTDesign

Tags: database, eclipse, birt

I want to change one of the query text in my report based on a parameter (showCountryId) which I'm passing to the report. Here is what I want to do,

if showCountryId === false,

> Select count(item) as cnt from items group items.type;

else

> Select country.id, count(item) as cnt from items join country group by country.id, items.type;

Does anyone know a way that can do this in my Birt rptDesign file ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the query text in the data set's beforeOpen event, but you cannot change the number of output columns.